# Is there a way to generate instances of a class

Tags: python

I'm trying to make sort of log in system but I'm not sure how to store data other than manually making lots of variables to store the names and passwords

```
class Acc:
   def __init__(self, name='', passw=''):
       self.name = name
       self.passw = passw

acc1 = Acc('ab','qw')
acc2 = Acc('kl', 'jm')
acc3 = Acc()
acc4 = Acc()
# ...
# etc
```

I want to make a function that
creates an empty variable 'accx'  then make it an instance of a class Acc()
then have the user fill their name and password with the input function.
`accx = Acc(input('name: '),input('password: ') )`
I'm sorry if the question is very stupid but I'm very new to coding
so help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why would you do that and not create instances as and when you get input?

Comment: you don't have to pre-instantiate instances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the `Acc` instances in a list or dictionary. Then you don't have to make many variable names, and you can quickly reference any `Acc` instance.

I assume you aren't using this program for anything with sensitive data, but as best practice, you should enter passwords with the `getpass.getpass` function.

```
import getpass

class Acc:
    def __init__(self, name, passw):
        self.name = name
        self.passw = passw

# Hold all Acc instances in one list.
all_accs = []

def new_acc():
    name = input('name: ')
    passw = getpass.getpass('password: ')
    a = Acc(name=name, passw=passw)
    all_accs.append(a)

new_acc()  # enter name and password

# Now all_accs[0] references the `Acc` created in the line above.
```

The process would be similar if you want to store the `Acc` instances in a dictionary. You can map the user's name to their `Acc` instance.

```
# Hold all Acc instances in one list.
all_accs = {}

def new_acc():
    name = input('name: ')
    if name in all_accs:  # Check for existing name
        raise ValueError("name already exists")
    passw = getpass.getpass('password: ')
    a = Acc(name=name, passw=passw)
    all_accs[name] = a
    
new_acc()  # enter "John" and password

# Now all_accs["John"] references the `Acc` created in the line above.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change attributes after the instantiation. :)

```
accx = Acc()
accx.name = input('name:')
accx.passw= input('password:')
```

Comment: This doesn't address his primary question, which if I read it right, is "how do I store a bunch of Acc objects without creating a whole bunch of variables".  The other answer gives a great answer to that question.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a `dict` (dictionary) to store your info?

Generally you'd like a database of some sorts, but sometimes a simple `dict` can help at the start:

```
import getpass

accounts = {}
while (name := input("Name: ")) != "!exit":
    passwd = getpass.getpass()  # Safer.
    accounts[name] = Acc(name, passwd)
```

Running it:

```
Name: Hey
Password:
Name: Hello
Password:
Name: !exit
>>> accounts
{'Hey': <__main__.Acc object at 0x000001BA01DF02E0>, 'Hello': <__main__.Acc object at 0x000001BA01F26850>}
>>> accounts["Hey"].passw
"I'm secret"
```